# Problem with Icelandic characters in Beamer

Tags: beamer, characters, input-encodings, font-encodings

I am doing a Beamer presentation based on an article, so I do a lot of copy and paste from one document to another. Basically everything is working fine, but for some reason, the Icelandic special characters that I use in some examples and that come out fine in the article, just appear as black squares on the slides in the Beamer presentation, although I load the same packages in the preamble. Heres an example of the preamble and the relevant document commands:

```
\documentclass[t,compress]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

}

\title{XXX}
\author{ZZZ}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\frame {

\ex. \ag. Jón harmar að [Þessa bók] \textbf{skuli} ég hafa lesið.\label{4a} \\
Jon regrets that this book shall I have read.\\
``John is sorry that I'll read this book.''\\

\bg. Hann efast um að hun \textbf{hafa} [ekki] hitt Þennan mann.\label{4b} \\
He doubts about that she has not met this man.\\
``He doubts that she has not met this man.''\\

}

... 

\end{document}
```

Any ideas why the charachters won't print in beamer when they do in the `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: Remove `\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `aeguill` package: it was an interesting hack several years ago, when Type1 versions of the European Modern fonts were not available. Now it should be regarded as obsolete.

Without `\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}` I get (ignoring the two errors that are unrelated)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a dream. Wonder why it only causes that problem in beamer, and not in articles...?